# returning value from main() without glibc

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to return a value from main() when compiling without GLIBC and it doesn't work. Lets this example that I found on internet:

```
[niko@localhost tests]$ cat stubstart.S 
.globl _start

_start:
    call main
    movl $1, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80
[niko@localhost tests]$ cat m.c
int main(int argc,char **argv) {

    return(90);

}
[niko@localhost tests]$ gcc -nostdlib stubstart.S -o m m.c 
[niko@localhost tests]$ ./m
[niko@localhost tests]$ echo $?
0
[niko@localhost tests]$
```

Now, if I compile with GLIBC I get the return value just fine:

```
[niko@localhost tests]$ gcc -o mglibc m.c
[niko@localhost tests]$ ./mglibc 
[niko@localhost tests]$ echo $?
90
[niko@localhost tests]$
```

So, aparently the returning is not done correctly in stubstart.S , how do I make it right? (Linux only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't provide `main()`'s return value to `_exit()`.

If you do it that way:

```
.globl _start

_start:
    call main
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

you save the return value from `eax` to `ebx`, where the exit code it is expected to be.